# PowerBuilder Migration

Tags: migration, powerbuilder

While migrating one .PBT, it is not getting completely migrated and PBDs are not getting generated. Instead of that it is asking for migration again and again continuously.
I want to know why it is asking for migration as I load the target file.
In which condition the migrating of PBT will be continuously ask to migrate

Comment: It's not clear what action is happening here. Migrating usually happens when you open a target with PBLs from a previous version; creating PBDs happens when you run a project (to create executables like PBDs). Also, when migrations fail, there are usually messages describing the failure. These migration failure messages need to be addressed before trying to create executables, and there is no description of that activity. Obviously something is going wrong, but there's not enough information here to say what it is.

Comment: Does the target build in the version of PB you're migrating from?

Comment: Target is not being generated first of all.
Actually i Have opened PB 10.5 code in 12.0 which asks migration
but target is not being generated

Comment: So, opening a target from a previous version is not supposed to "generate" anything; it is supposed to convert the PBLs to the new version. (You backed up the 10.5 version of the code before you started this, right?) The result will be your existing target and PBL files converted in-place (i.e. replacing your existing files) to the new version. After you open and migrate the target, is it still visible under the workspace in the system tree? If so, you're ready to go.

Comment: Yes For sure I backed up the 10.5 version. But it is not visible under the workspace in the system tree.

Comment: I'm still in the dark as to what you've done. My suggestion would be to a) describe step-by-step what you've done, b) describe where the results vary from what you'd expect, c) provide some example errors from the error pane. (The error pane is key to failed migrations and we haven't heard anything about it yet.) I think you'll have better luck editing/rewriting your question, since comments don't allow much formatting.

Comment: Please do this: Take a fresh copy of your PB10.5 code in a new folder. Create a workspace and add your 10.5 target. PB will migrate. Save the whole log. Open it in an editor and delete everything but errors and warnings. If necessary, substitute any proprietary object/pbl names with something made up, but please include all errors and warnings. Add your errors and warnings to your question. You also have not answered my question about whether the target builds in 10.5. Did you find these PBLs on a flash drive in the parking lot?

Comment: Migrating to PB 12.0 from 10.5 has been successfully done with some warnings.While executing the .exe it is giving an error as "Registry access Manager has not been initialised,Unable to process registry access requests"

Comment: The warnings you got may be a clue or they may mean nothing. Usually you get warnings when you have duplicate objects. The error when you run isn't PB. It's something coded in your app. Search for those strings to find where it's failing.

Comment: Did you try this? Create a new empty application. Add one pbl from existing application. Regenerate all datawindows. Regenerate windows and other objects one by one. Some will fail because of dependencies. Eventually you will find one that fails for non-dependency error. Edit the source and comment the line(s) with errors and save. Add each PBL one by one until you have the application migrated. Now you can open the real application and perform full rebuild.